# How to select date of datepicker in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am automating the application through protractor and as part of one testcase need to select the date, the date-picker definition is as below. I tried to select the date using sendkeys which is not working. 
[image]

```
element(by.lid("new-transaction-doat-field)).sendKeys("24 Aug 2019");
```

Please help me in to select the date.

Note: lid is the custom attribute and to select the value by lid, create a custom attribute method in protractor

Comment: `element(by.lid("new-transaction-doat-field))` represents the datepicker which is not a Input element, thus it can't accept `sendKeys`. You should invoke on its child `element(by.css( '[lid="new-transaction-doat-field"] > span > input'))`, but this Input set to readonly, so you can't use `sendKeys` to input date, you can use `setAttribute('value', "24 Aug 2019")`

Comment: Try sending keys to the input, if no luck get back to me I have a few other ideas

Comment: @yong, Thanks for your time and response. we should use the method as `document.getElementbyId("dateModel").setAtttribute('value' , "24 Aug 2019");` right? Can you please let me know how to use setAttribute method here we doesn't have id or name. How to identify uniquely?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, Thanks for your time and response. no luck with sendKeys method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to select the date through datepicker where 'sendKeys' won't work as input is disabled. The solution is like how manually we will traverse through the calendar and select the date.

The code is as below:

```
this.selectDate = function (dateElement, dateValue, yearButton, arrowButton) {
        var splitDate = dateValue.split('/');
        var year = splitDate[2];
        var month = splitDate[1];
        var day = splitDate[0];
        var monthName = getMonthName(month);

        dateElement.click()
            .then(() => yearButton.click())
            .then(() => yearButton.click())
            .then(() => selectYear(year, arrowButton))
            .then(() => element(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + year + "']")).click())
            .then(() => element(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + monthName + "']")).click())
            .then(() => element(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + day + "']")).click());

    };

    async function selectYear(year, arrowButton) {
        for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            var present  = await element(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + year + "']")).isPresent()
            if(present) {
                break;
            } else {
                await arrowButton.click();
            }
        }
    }
```

function takes inputs as dateElement, dateValue, yearButton - which is center button to traverse to years, arrowButton - previous or next button in the calendar

[image]

First script clicks on the year button in the center in the above image it is  'September 2019' , after that '2019' year calendar comes, it clicks on that again.
Then 2001 to 2019 calendar comes as below
[image]

if the year displays it clicks on that otherwise it clicks on 'previous' or 'next' button based on the date to select until it got displayed (looping for 10 times to search for the year, if not in 10 clicks throws error).

After year clicked, it clicks on month and day.

Comment: That is great. But one needs to remember something. While passing dateValue make sure it is String within quotation mark. Also I needed to work around with the getMonthname() function. I have created an array of months. The months' names are like JAN, FEB because my HTML DOM renders the months name like this for the website I am working on now.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues in your given code:

1) Should interact with a Input html element

2) `sendKeys()` can't interact with a readonly Input html element.

```
// because protractor not support invoke setAttribute api directly,
// need to using executeScript to inject DOM Javascript snippet into browser 
// then execute the snippet in browser

browser.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])",
    element(by.css( '[lid="new-transaction-doat-field"] > span > input')).getWebElement(),
    "24 Aug 2019"
)
```

Keep in mind, `setAttribute()` is not simulating user interact with web page from UI.

Please confirm it's acceptable from your test perspective.

Comment: Sorry, it is entering the value in automation script, it is not saved. After selection and do the operation, selected date was not there, as that selection is optional so didn't get any error.

Comment: If the web page developed by your workmate, ask them for a javascript snippet which can change the select date when execute it in browser console.  (This snippet should use Angular api, like developer doing unit test on this datepicker). Then use `browser.executeScript()` to execute that snippet

Comment: this is the approach I was thinking about, if the above doesn't work, try to inject a script to set `readonly` and `ng-disabled` attributes to `null` and then set its value

Comment: but it' can't effect the binded ng-model from which the angular code expect to get the select date. So the workable approach is to call angualr api to change the value of binded ng-modle.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the `.sendKeys()` on the input?

`element(by.model('dateModel')).sendKeys('dd mmm yyyy');`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time and response. I tried this but it is selecting the current date instead of what ever i sent.