# Can't open date picker using .click() in protractor > "Failed: element not interactable"

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

When I try to trigger a date picker, an error is shown 'Failed: element not interactable'

Structure of an element is the following

```
<div class="datepicker-input-wrapper datepicker-input-wrapper-start">
  <div class="datepicker-trigger"></div>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker-input datepicker-input-start" autocomplete="off">
  <span class="">Anreise</span>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
var start_date = element(by.className('datepicker-trigger'));
    start_date.click();
```

I expect to see date picker opened
There are no other locators except classes, that's why I used by.className

Tried to maximize browser window or scroll to element, it didn't help

Comment: try putting your js in onload event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select date of datepicker in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657334/how-to-select-date-of-datepicker-in-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier if you just use the input with sendKeys like this:

```
element(by.css('.datepicker-input.datepicker-input-start')).sendKeys('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Or whatever date format it accepts